# Неоднонаправленный глагол "летать"

Tags: морфология

Известно, что глагол "летал" является неоднонаправленным, то есть он означает не какой-то конкретный полет в одном направлении и понятие в целом. То есть означает либо действие без направления, либо полет с направлением, но и с перерывами, либо непрерывное, но разнонаправленное движение.

Однако вполне грамотной является фраза "Я один раз летал в Питер", что не вяжется с вышеизложенным правилом употребления неоднонаправленных глаголов движения. Почему так?

Answer (score 2):

Сравните два предложения:

(1)"Я один раз летел в Питер, и вот что случилось на борту". Рассказ о том, что происходит при полете, однонаправленный глагол "лететь".

(2) Я один раз летал в Питер и с трудом снял там квартиру. Здесь глагол "летать" обозначает, что герой рассказа прилетел в Питер, но потом через некоторое время вернулся домой.

Также: я шел в магазин - я ходил в магазин (и уже вернулся).